# XElement vs BulkCopy to insert into a database from Excel

Tags: asp.net, database, excel

I have an Excel sheet with 100 columns and 200 rows. I want to insert this into a database table - would using XElement or Bulk Copy be a better approach?

Comment: Please give more detail and tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to do this programatically, or just as a one-off ? If you're only doing it once or not very often, SQL Enterprise Manager/Management Studio does a pretty good job of importing Excel spreadsheets as tables.

EDIT: -

If you're doing this programatically then I would suggest creating an SSIS package to do the job. Have a look here - [Import from Excel to Sql Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103994/import-from-excel-to-sql-table)